# Can func get the lineno who call itself? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c

I've a problem , as the following code discribe itself.

```
1  #include<stdlib.h>
2  #include<stdio.h>
3  void log()
4  {
5         printf("Log [Line:%d]\n",__LINE__);
6  }
7  int main()
8  {
9         log();
10        log();
11 }
```

The expected result is 
Log [Line:9] 
Log [Line:10] 
But, the fact is
Log [Line:5] 
Log [Line:5]

No surprising, **LINE** has been substituted at the pre-process stage as 5. 
My Question is, how to design the log function to get the expected result? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to write a macro:

```
#define LOG printf("Log [Line:%d]\n",__LINE__)
```

then use it:

```
int main() {
    LOG;
    LOG;
}
```

This works because the macro is expanded at its point of use, giving the `__LINE__` macro the correct value.

Comment: In the case of C++, you could also use an inline function.

Comment: @waffleman No you can't - macro expansion (of the `__LINE__` macro) takes place before the compiler sees the code.

Comment: An inline function won't work - `__LINE__` is a preprocessor macro so is substituted during the preprocessor, not during function inlining. (edit: ninja'd)

Answer (score 4):

A macro can overcome this, by passing in the `__LINE__` as a parameter to the invoked function.

Another, perhaps complementary approach is to pass some context to the function as a parameter, with a default value that says 'use the line number'.  This is illustrated by this code snippet which is doing error handling with the pattern:

```
int read_byte(FILE* f,int line=0) {
  int ret = fgetc(f);
  if(-1 == ret)
     throw (line? line: __LINE__);
  return ret;
}

int read_uint16(FILE* f,int line=0) {
  int hi = read_byte(f,(line? line: __LINE__));
  int lo = read_byte(f,(line? line: __LINE__));
  return (hi<<8)|lo;
}

int main() {
  ...
  try {
    int i = read_uint16(f,__LINE__);
  } catch(int line) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error at line %d\n",line);
  }
  ...
}
```

Finally, this all smacks of wanting to get a stack trace out of C/C++ code (especially in the error handling cases).  Look at [`VALGRIND_PRINTF_BACKTRACE(format, ...)`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your existing function slightly, and wrap it in a macro:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define log() real_log(__LINE__)

void real_log(int line)
{
       printf("Log [Line:%d]\n", line);
}

int main()
{
       log();
       log();
}
```