# Print the file name, line number and function name of a calling function - C Prog

Tags: c

I want to create log.c file with containing info(), debug() and error() functions.
These functions are working without printing file name, line number,..etc.
So when I call one of this function I want to dump the file name, line number, and function name of the caller. So how do we exactly trace back?
Is there a way to trace back on C or, if we use macros, how can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651850/can-func-get-the-lineno-who-call-itself-c-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ line number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849832/c-c-line-number)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'd pass the data to the function through parameters (maybe get the help of a macro)

```
int info(const char *fname, int lineno, const char *fxname, ...) { /* ... */ }
int debug(const char *fname, int lineno, const char *fxname, ...) { /* ... */ }
int error(const char *fname, int lineno, const char *fxname, ...) { /* ... */ }
```

And to call them

```
info(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ...);
debug(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ...);
error(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ...);
```

Note: `__func__` is C99; gcc, in mode C89 has `__FUNCTION__`

Comment: Is there a way to to create these kind of functions, without passing __FILE__,..etc parameters all the time?

Comment: Yes, with a macro. For instance, for C99 (which has variadic macros): `#define INFO(...) info(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: i m using same function #define INFO(...) info(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__) in cpp but it giving me errors when i include same header file from different classes ? do you know how i can implement same in C++.

Answer (score 13):

If you use macros, I believe you can make this work by using `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__FUNCTION__`. For example,

```
#define INFO(msg) \
    fprintf(stderr, "info: %s:%d: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", msg);
```

You could use functions too, but you would need to pass in `__FILE__`, etc. to make sure they had the correct value.

Comment: `gcc -std=gnu99` says `__LINE__` is an integer and warns about casting it to `char *`. Shouldn't the second line be `fprintf(stderr, "info: %s:%d: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \ ` (`%s` replaced by `%d`)?

Comment: Fixed! Leaking some old-school Python there.